# Android: RecyclerView's ImageView get Recycled at Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-viewholder

In my app I have a RecyclerView. Each item of the RecyclerView contains ImageView that represents bookmarked items.

I implemented a logic that checks for item state for toggling the ImageView's content (bookmarked state) at onBindViewHolder() method inside my custom adapter.

**The problem I have is that when I scroll the view, I get recycled ImageView's asset although my logic is implemented at onBindViewHolder().**

I already try these solutions here but no help:

- [Repeat background on element with scroll RecycleAdapter and scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662607/repeat-background-on-element-with-scroll-recycleadapter-and-scroll)
- [RecyclerView causes issue when recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265865/recyclerview-causes-issue-when-recycling)
- [recycled recyerview item keeps the old background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122098/recycled-recyerview-item-keeps-the-old-background-color/37122316#37122316)

Everyone said that you must implement logic inside the onBindViewHolder() method and make the logic dependent on the data model, but I already did that.

Here is my RecyclerAdapter.java code:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.BasicViewHolder> {


Context mContext;
List<DataModel> mDataModels;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataModels) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataModels = dataModels;
}

@Override
public BasicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.item_layout;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);

    BasicViewHolder viewHolder = new BasicViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BasicViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataModels.size();
}

public class BasicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final TextView titleTextView;
    public final ImageView bookmarkImageView;

    public BasicViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        bookmarkImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    void bind(int listIndex) {
        titleTextView.setText(mDataModels.get(listIndex).getTitle());

        //I think here is where the problem is being caused
        if(mDataModels.get(listIndex).isSelected()) bookmarkImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bookmark));
    }
}
}
```

[DataModelList only indicates to change ImageView of item at position 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycq1V.png)

[Nevertheless other items get the same ImageView when scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR6Vf.png)

I hope you guys can help me, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you only update `bookmarkImageView` when the item being bound is selected. Because of the way view recycling works, it is important to make sure to *always* update each view. In your case, that means showing a bookmark when the item is selected, and *hiding the bookmark when the item is not selected*.

Try something like this:

```
if (mDataModels.get(listIndex).isSelected()) {
    bookmarkImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);
} else {
    bookmarkImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I just had to implement the else case :P Marked as solution. Thank you very much!